# Find out how to fix maxClauseCount is set to 1024 error in Gravitee.io

Tags: mongodb, api, elasticsearch, boolean, gravitee

I have many API's registered in Gravitee.io. I tried to add the following:

index.query.bool.max_clause_count: 10240

To the file elasticsearch.yml

But it didn't work, I don't know how to change it in gravitee

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to change the max clause count of a query setting in Elasticsearch than correct setting is below as explained in [Search settings doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-settings.html#search-settings)

```
indices.query.bool.max_clause_count
```